# Frame doesn't get displayed in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

test_frame = tk.Frame()
testlabel = tk.Label(text="testLabel", master = test_frame)
test_frame.grid(row=0,column=0)

text_area = tk.Text()
text_area.grid(row=0,column=1)

window.mainloop()
```

I am learning python GUI and was trying a project on my own. I started with trying to distribute the window into sections(row and columns) and then putting the widgets in them. I made a frame and a text box and tried to fit them side by side, so I decided to put them in a 1x2 grid(1 row 2 columns). The problem is the text box shows up but the frame doesn't, I even added a test label to see the frame but it just doesn't show up. I have tried to width and height as well but it doesn't work.

Please show me what's missing.

Thank you.

Comment: You didn't specify the parent of the label and text box, so they will be created as children of root window.  Therefore the frame has no child and its size will be 1x1.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to use 'place', because with grid, or pack(side='left') the `Text widget has a default size of 80x24 characters`(info from @Bryan Oakley
), but with place I managed to leave one next to the other.

```py
import tkinter as tk

# root
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
# frame
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
# label
label = tk.Label(frame, text='Test', bg='red')
label.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=0.5, relheight=1)
# text frame
text = tk.Text(frame, bg='light blue')
text.place(relx=0.5, rely=0, relwidth=0.5, relheight=1, )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: Example]

Comment: _"the Text widget doesn't respect the interface"_ - the text widget has a default size of 80x24 characters.

Answer (score 0):

All you're really missing is placing the label on the frame, just `pack` or `grid` your test label just like you do with the frame or the textbox:

```py
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

test_frame = tk.Frame()
test_label = tk.Label(test_frame, text="testLabel")
test_label.pack()  # this is what you're missing
test_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

text_area = tk.Text()
text_area.grid(row=0, column=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The frame *is* visible. However, because you haven't given it a size, and because none of its children are visible, it has a size of 1x1 pixels. This can be illustrated pretty easily by giving the frame an explicit size and a distinctive background color:

```
test_frame = tk.Frame(width=20, height=20, background="red")
```

Notice that the frame is centered in the column. That is because `grid` will center a widget by default if there is more space than necessary for the widget.

[image: screenshot]

The real solution in this specific case is to make sure you call `pack` or `grid` on the label that is inside of `test_frame`. That will force the frame to grow to fit its contents.

```
testlabel.pack()
```

[image: screenshot with label]

Notice that you once again can't see the frame. That's because by default it shrinks or expands to exactly fit its children and you haven't instructed it to expand to fill the space allocated to it.

You can tell `grid` to expand the widget to fill the space by using the `sticky` attribute. It takes characters that are points in a compass. When you specify `"nsew"` the frame will "stick" to the north (top), south (bottom), east (right side) and west (left side) parts of the column.

```
test_frame.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="nsew")
```

Notice that this forces the label to the top of the column. Since you didn't specify a side when calling `pack`, it defaults to "top" so the label is stuck to the top of the frame. Since the frame now fills the column, the top of the frame is now at the top of the window, and that is where the label is placed.

[image: screenshot using sticky attribute]